# Transformation.switchmap not returning result unless search term changes

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a LiveData<List> which needs to return accounts based on search query, if no query return all accounts. Here is my code, I have used in my ViewModel class, but upon initialisation no accounts are shown, only when i change searchTerm does it start to show results, and on making search term empty also shows results.

```
    val searchTerm = MutableLiveData<String>()

    val accounts : LiveData<List<AccountModel>> = Transformations.switchMap(searchTerm){

            if(it.isNullOrEmpty()){
                Transformations.map(accountRepository.accountDAO.getAccounts()){
                    it.toDomainModel()
                }
            }else{
                Transformations.map(accountRepository.accountDAO.getSearchedList(it)){
                    it.toDomainModel()
                }
            }

        }
```

Can someone guide me with what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use initial value. Your switchMap isn't triggered before your searhTerm gets the first value.

```
val searchTerm = MutableLiveData<String>("")
```

Comment: It worked, thanks, I have used LiveData before, never needed to initialize like this